# I can't figure out why dropna() does not work in my code

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following block of code where I'm trying to drop rows, which contains 'date_added' missing values, however even after trying variety of different parameters, it still does not work properly. I'm a bit confused, because I've tried literally everything

```py
import pandas 

netflix_dataset = pandas.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv")

def process_date_missing_values() -> None:
    netflix_dataset.date_added.dropna(inplace=True)

def process_duration_missing_values() -> None:
    netflix_dataset.duration.dropna(inplace=True)

def process_rating_missing_values() -> None:
    netflix_dataset.rating.dropna(inplace=True)

# Removing Missing Values from the Dataset 

def remove_missing_values():
   
    process_date_missing_values()
    process_rating_missing_values()
    process_duration_missing_values()

remove_missing_values() 

cleaned_data = netflix_dataset 

print(cleaned_data.isna().sum()) # there missing values still exists
```

I can provide more information, if necessary, but truly apologize, if it turns out to be something obvious causing this problem, I'm only starting out with pandas

Comment: Could you provide a short example of a file to test your code ? That would make debugging it easier

Comment: I think that "inplace" approach is deprecated in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `netflix_dataset.dropna(subset=['date_added'], inplace=True)`.

Comment: thank you a looooooooooot

Comment: :))))))))))))))